# Point raw pointer to a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I started programming in C++ after a 1-year break, and I am having difficulties here and there (not that I really knew it before the break).

My current problem is that I don't know how to use pointers properly.

I have the following `std::vector`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IHittable>> world;
```

Where `IHittable` is the interface of `Hittable` objects.

Now, in this `std::vector`, multiple derivations of `IHittable` are pushed, like `Sphere`, `Triangle`, etc.

Each of these derived classes has a function `intersects()` like this:

```cpp
Intersection Sphere::intersects(const Ray & ray)
{
    auto x = ...
    ...
    return {x, this};
}
```

`Intersection` looks like this:

```cpp
class Intersection
{
    public:
        Intersection(double t, IHittable * object);
        [[nodiscard]] double t() const;
        [[nodiscard]] IHittable * object() const;
    private:
        double t_;
        IHittable * object_ = nullptr;
};
```

I really don't know how to write this code correctly.

I need to return a `this` pointer from the member function `intersects()` of an object which is itself allocated dynamically and is stored in a `std::shared_ptr`.

Is there a way to handle this?

Another example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IHittable>> world;
world.push_back(std::make_shared<Sphere>());
auto s = Intersection(4.0, world[0]);
```

Should work.

PS: I could just create multiple `std::vector`s without `std::shared_ptr`:

```cpp
std::vector<Sphere> spheres;
std::vector<Triangles> spheres;
...
```

But IMHO, it would be nice to iterate over every object at once.

PS2: I am now using shared_from_this() and most of my code works, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and its [`shared_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) method? Change `Intersection` to hold a `std::shared_ptr<IHittable>` rather than a raw `IHittable*` pointer.

Comment: If you've got shared pointers, you might as well share them, otherwise you're spending resources on the sharing without using it AND telling readers that the variable is shared when it isn't. Lie to people and they make poor judgements about how best to use your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, why doesn't `this` work? Are you worried about preserving the lifetime of the `IHittable`?

Comment: @JeremyWest, with "this" I had this bug "https://i.stack.imgur.com/H45ns.png".

Comment: Oh, I see, so you mean specifically that the line
`auto s = Intersection(4.0, world[0]);`
fails, right? Try this:
`auto s = Intersection(4.0, world[0].get());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this sounds like a good fit for [std::enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) as Remy pointed out in the comments.

I whipped up a simplified example which hopefully makes it clear how it can be used to achieve what you're after.

```
class Intersection;

class IHittable : public std::enable_shared_from_this<IHittable> { 
public:
    virtual Intersection intersects( ) = 0;
    virtual void print( ) const = 0;
    virtual ~IHittable( ) = default;
};

class Intersection {
public:
    Intersection( std::shared_ptr<IHittable> object )
        : object_{ std::move( object ) }
    { }

    void print_shape( ) const {
        object_->print( );
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<IHittable> object_;
};

class Square : public IHittable {
public:
    Intersection intersects( ) override {
        return Intersection{ shared_from_this( ) };
    }

    void print( ) const override {
        std::cout << "Square\n";
    }
};

int main( ) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IHittable>> objects{ 
        std::make_shared<Square>( ) };

    const auto intersect{ objects.front( )->intersects( ) };
    intersect.print_shape( );
}
```